# Mssql old table to new table different data types and empties

Tags: sql, sql-server, import

I have a new table I created for a membership application for a local club, anyway there existing software stored info in a DBF file I can import this into mssql as a table that's no trouble I am just stuck on merging the old data into the new table.

This is the old Table Structure (From DBF imported into mssql)

```
[NUMBER] [int] NULL,
[LASTNAME] [char](30) NULL,
[FIRSTNAME] [char](20) NULL,
[TITLE] [char](5) NULL,
[SALUTATION] [char](25) NULL,
[ADD1] [char](30) NULL,
[ADD2] [char](30) NULL,
[ADD3] [char](30) NULL,
[TOWN] [char](30) NULL,
[COUNTY] [char](30) NULL,
[POSTCODE] [char](8) NULL,
[TELEPHONE] [char](30) NULL,
[TYPE] [char](1) NULL,
[PAID] [char](1) NULL,
[COMMITTEE] [char](30) NULL,
[WARNINGS] [int] NULL,
[MONTHDRAW] [int] NULL,
[WOMANS] [char](1) NULL,
[SENIORCIT] [char](1) NULL,
[DOB] [datetime] NULL,
[AMOUNTCLUB] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
[DATEPAY] [datetime] NULL,
[AMOUNTBRAN] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
[AMOUNTDUE] [decimal](6, 2) NULL
```

This is the new Table:

```
[MemberID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Surname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[HouseNumber] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[Street] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[County] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[Postcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[TelephoneNumber] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[MobileNumber] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[EmailAddress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[DOB] [date] NULL,
[Age] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[SeniorCitizen] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[Warnings] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MembershipCategory] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[ServiceBranch] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[Paid] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[ToPay] [float] NULL,
[DatePaidIn] [date] NULL,
[Entry] [tinyint] NULL,
[FOB] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[JoinDate] [date] NULL,
[SubscriptionYear] [date] NULL,
[TotalPaid] [float] NULL,
```

I am writing the insert like;

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MemberDetails] 
([MemberID],[Title],[FirstName],[Surname],[HouseNumber],[Street],[City],[County],[Postcode],[TelephoneNumber],[MobileNumber],[EmailAddress],[DOB],[Age],[SeniorCitizen],[Warnings],[MembershipCategory],[ServiceBranch],[Paid],[ToPay],[DatePaidIn],[Entry],[FOB],[JoinDate],[SubscriptionYear],[TotalPaid])
SELECT [NUMBER], [TITLE], [FIRSTNAME], [LASTNAME], [ADD1], [ADD2], [TOWN], [COUNTY], [POSTCODE], [TELEPHONE]
FROM [dbo].[MEMBERS] 
GO
```

I got as far as that column then realized "how do I do empty values as no one in the old table had a mobile record?" also do I need to do Select AS "new column name" for the old table values?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you go from `OldTable` to `NewTable`, adding an `answer` column to the original `question` column:

```
insert  NewTable
        (question, answer)
select  question
,       '42' -- Specify a literal or default value
from    OldTable
```

You can also omit the new column from the `insert` list:

```
insert  NewTable
        (question)
select  question
from    OldTable
```

This will copy the `question` column and put the default value `null` in the `answer` column.

You do not have to use aliases in the select list.  It's strictly order based.  This would work fine:

```
insert  NewTable
        (question)
select  question as CeciNEstPasUnePipe
from    OldTable
```

Comment: I just asked this on IRC and now I feel really stupid ... thanks for that though :)